# PHP Pagination links increment

Tags: php, pagination

Basically i want to limit the amount of numbers displayed on my page, but currently it's displaying 31 numbers, because their is 31 pages of results, i'd like to show 5 links and just increment after every page,

Here's how they're currently being displayed

`[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8] etc..`

Here's what i'd like

`[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]`

What i'd like i just but once you select for example number 8, it'd place that number in the middle and 2 links either side for example like this

```
[6] [7] [8] [9] [10]
```

Here's the current code that i'm using

```
function showPageNumbers($totalrows,$page,$limit){  
    $query_string = $this->queryString();   
    $pagination_links = null;       
    $numofpages = $totalrows / $limit;      
    for($i = 1; $i <= $numofpages; $i++){               
      if($i == $page){
            $pagination_links .= '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }else{ 
            $pagination_links .= '<li><a href="?page='.$i.'&'.$query_string.'" title="go to page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>'; 
        }
    }

    if(($totalrows % $limit) != 0){          
        if($i == $page){
            $pagination_links .= '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }else{
            $pagination_links .= '<li><a href="?page='.$i.'&'.$query_string.'" title="go to page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }
    }   
    return $pagination_links;
}
```

Comment: First question here, please read what to do [when you get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have modified function like:

```
function showPageNumbers($totalrows, $page, $limit){

    $query_string = $this->queryString();
    $pagination_links = null;
    $numofpages = $totalrows / $limit;

    $linksPerPage = 5;

    $firstNum = $page - round(($linksPerPage)/2);
    if($firstNum < 1) 
        $firstNum =1;

    $lastNum = $firstNum + $linksPerPage -1;
    if($lastNum > $numofpages)
         $lastNum = $numofpages;

    for($i = $firstNum; $i <= $lastNum; $i++){
        if($i == $page){
            $pagination_links .= '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }else{
            $pagination_links .= '<li><a href="?page='.$i.'&'.$query_string.'" title="go to page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }
    }

    return $pagination_links;
}
```